Issue with WordPress Automatically Assigning Terms to Multiple Posts
Hello WordPress community,
I'm encountering an issue where WordPress is automatically assigning newly created terms to multiple posts in my installation. When I create a new term (custom taxonomy: course-code) using the WordPress admin interface, the term seems to be assigned to multiple posts, rather than just the intended one.
I've tried the following steps to troubleshoot the issue:
Deactivated all plugins and switched to a default WordPress theme to rule out conflicts.
Reviewed custom code in my theme's functions.php file and custom plugins to check for any potential conflicts or errors.
Enabled WordPress debugging to see if any relevant errors or notices are being generated.
Despite these efforts, the issue persists, and I'm not sure what else to try. Can anyone provide guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
